# Staging test error: replacement fee too low

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, dapps, hardhat-deploy

I am running a staging test in Goerli Network, this is an simple test to test a fund and withdraw function but i am facing error while running it. Hoping some-one could help me through it.

Test:-

```
 it("staging - allows people to fund and withdraw", async function () {
        const startingContractBalance =
          await fundMeContract.provider.getBalance(fundMeContract.address);
        await fundMeContract.fund({ value: sendValue });
        const fundedContractBalance = await fundMeContract.provider.getBalance(
          fundMeContract.address
        );
        const tx = await fundMeContract.cheaperWithdraw();
        //const tx = await fundMe.withdraw()
        await tx.wait(1);
        const endingContractBalance = await fundMeContract.provider.getBalance(
          fundMeContract.address
        );
        assert.equal(startingContractBalance, "0");
        assert.equal(fundedContractBalance.toString(), sendValue.toString());
        assert.equal(endingContractBalance, "0");
      });
```

Error:

```
 1) fund
       staging - allows people to fund and withdraw:
     Error: replacement fee too low [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (/Volumes/official/avi/projects/workspaces/BlockChain/Phase1/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (/Volumes/official/avi/projects/workspaces/BlockChain/Phase1/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Volumes/official/avi/projects/workspaces/BlockChain/Phase1/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.7.1)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at checkError (node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:112:16)
      at /Volumes/official/avi/projects/workspaces/BlockChain/Phase1/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:265:24
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: You might have a pending transaction stuck in the pending pool. Either wait until it is mined or try replacing it.

Comment: Hey @Ismael , I had been been using interacting with goerli network via alchemy rpc. I am still in learning phase can you please shed some light on why this is happening and how can i see the pending transaction and correct this? :)

Comment: Look if the address has pending transaction in a goerli block explorer. The cause could be that the gas price is too low.

Comment: @Ismael, i checked in goerli etherscan and find no pending transaction. From address: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd281ef049bd51a460d744a27e411350cf2ffb97e 
To address: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xADd3C58237D374B16d09D358435C229CdE1286b1

Comment: It seems fine now. does the problem happen again? Recent transaction have gas price around 1-2 gwei, and there were a couple of previous transactions with gas price of 0.1 gwei that might have taken longer to be mined.